# python selenium save value of textfileld

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have made a record on selenium ide and exported it for python webdriver, i want to store the value of a textfield but i cant get it to work..

The script is pretty much standard except this part:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re




class Shorturl(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://shorturl.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_shorturl(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
    driver.find_element_by_name("longurl").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("longurl").send_keys("http://lalala.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"image\"]").click()

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"submit\"]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("txtfld").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    noah = driver.find_element_by_id("txtfld").text
    print noah

    file = open("datafile.txt", "w")
    file.write(noah)
    file.close()

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
    return True

def is_alert_present(self):
    try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_text = alert.text
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert_text
    finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

def tearDown(self):
    #self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

it clicks it but it doesnt prints it or saves it in the file.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you note the actual url you are trying to parse from?

Comment: Typically with a 'text field' if you want to know what `value` it is set you, you will need to get that `value` rather than its `text`. `driver.find_element_by_id("txtfld").get_attribute("value")`

Comment: got it, how can i give you a best answer or something, thank you very much for your help, have a great life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically with a 'text field' if you want to know what value it is set to, you will need to get that value rather than its text.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("txtfld").get_attribute("value")
```